# Compare two Timestamp in java

Tags: java, timestamp

How can I compare if `mytime` is between `fromtime` and `totime`:

```
Timestamp fromtime;
Timestamp totime;

Timestamp mytime;
```

Answer (score 78):

```
if(mytime.after(fromtime) && mytime.before(totime))
  //mytime is in between
```

Comment: Consider Maurice Perry response, if you want to include `fromTime` and `toTime`

Answer (score 19):

Use the `before` and `after` methods: [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

```
if (mytime.after(fromtime) && mytime.before(totime))
```

Answer (score 13):

From : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#compareTo(java.sql.Timestamp)

```
public int compareTo(Timestamp ts)
```

> Compares this Timestamp object to the given Timestamp object.
>       Parameters:
>           ts - the Timestamp object to be compared to this Timestamp object
>       Returns:
>           the value 0 if the two Timestamp objects are equal; a value less than 0 if this Timestamp object is before the given argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Timestamp object is after the given argument.
>       Since:
>           1.4

Answer (score 6):

```
if (!mytime.before(fromtime) && !mytime.after(totime))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort Timestamp as follows:

```
public int compare(Timestamp t1, Timestamp t2) {

    long l1 = t1.getTime();
    long l2 = t2.getTime();
    if (l2 > l1)
    return 1;
    else if (l1 > l2)
    return -1;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are [after](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#after%28java.sql.Timestamp%29) and [before](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#before%28java.sql.Timestamp%29) methods for `Timestamp` which will do the trick

Comment: broken links there

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.Date mytime = null;
if (mytime.after(now) && mytime.before(last_download_time) )
```

Worked for me

Comment: hmm .. a) that'll throw a NPE b) true only for future download, a timewarp ;-)

Comment: what is now in if (mytime.after(now))?

Answer (score 0):

All these solutions don't work for me, although the right way of thinking.

The following works for me:

```
if(mytime.isAfter(fromtime) || mytime.isBefore(totime) 
    // mytime is between fromtime and totime
```

Before I tried I thought about your solution with && too

Answer (score -3):

Just convert the timestamp in millisec representation. Use **getTime()** method.